# volumes and volumeMounts in Airflow Official Helm not working

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm, mounted-volumes

Just quickly checking if anyone also encountered an issue wherein the `volumeMounts` defined in the `values.yaml` file is not reflecting or being 'mounted' inside the airflow containers?

I have the following values in my `volumeMounts:` and `volumes:` section in my `values.yaml` file:

```
# Volumes for all airflow containers
volumes:
    - name: varconn
      secret:
        secretName: airflow-varconn-secret
        items:
        - key: var.env
          path: var.env
        - key: conn.env
          path: conn.env

# VolumeMounts for all airflow containers
volumeMounts:
    - name: varconn
      mountPath: /opt/airflow/secrets
      readOnly: true
```

In the code block above, what I'm trying to do is mount my files `var.env` and `conn.env` inside all of the airflow containers. Currently I have these files stored in a secret called `airflow-varconn-secret`.

Unfortunately this approach did not work and when I tried doing `exec` into one of the airflow containers, I don't see the 'secrets' DIR create nor the files I was trying to mount.

Next I tried:

```
webserver:
  # Mount additional volumes into webserver. It can be templated like in the following example:
  #   extraVolumes:
  #     - name: my-templated-extra-volume
  #       secret:
  #          secretName: '{{ include "my_secret_template" . }}'
  #          defaultMode: 0640
  #          optional: true
  #
  #   extraVolumeMounts:
  #     - name: my-templated-extra-volume
  #       mountPath: "{{ .Values.my_custom_path }}"
  #       readOnly: true
  extraVolumes:
    - name: varconn
      secrets:
        secretName: airflow-varconn-secret
        items:
        - key: var.env
          path: var.env
        - key: conn.env
          path: conn.env
        
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: varconn
      mountPath: /opt/airflow/varconn
      readOnly: true
```

In this code block, what I'm trying to do is load the same secret files inside the 'webserver' container. However, this is not working as well.

Can anyone please help how I can mount my secret files inside each airflow container? What am I doing wrong here?

Chart version: 1.5.0
Airflow version: 2.2.4

Thank you!